# android studio switch between multiple sdk version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

If I install multiple SDK version, how can I switch it between it to use new API or old API?

e.g. My android list target output as below:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
----------
id: 2 or "android-L"
     Name: Android L (Preview)
     Type: Platform
     API level: L
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

But when I try to create a L android application, it seems I still no see the new API for L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to target other versions, then you must install different "System Images"

[image: System Images Checked]

Then when you wish to create an AVD under "Target" there will be an extra option to target those versions.

This is only for AVDs(Virtual Devices) if you wish to code for older versions you will need to use support libraries

Comment: Does Android Studio will use AVD also? I guess AVD is used for emulator.

Comment: And do we need system image for android studio? I guess it's only used for emulator also!

Comment: Yea its only for emulator. You gave output of the 'android list targets' command which is a list of system images for emulators.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the Android L preview .. you will get some bugs

just use either Android 4.4W API20
or  Android 4.4.2 API 19

if you can't see one of both I suggest you to install a new version of android SDK Manger